# Position Drawer element at the bottom of the menu

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

how is it possible to position the menu point at the lower edge of the screen?
The best solution would be if you could simply change the style of the navigation options for each element.

Here is my App Navigator:

```
    const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
      {
        Einkaufsliste: {
          screen: MainScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            drawerIcon: <Icon name="shopping-cart" />
          }
        },
        Bearbeiten: {
          screen: BasketEditScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            drawerIcon: <Icon name="edit" />
          }
        }
      },

      {
        contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent
      }
    );
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `bottom: 0vh; position: absolute;` ?

Comment: So you want the last element in the drawer to be at the bottom? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @MichaelOstrovsky yeah thats correct

Comment: @stever No, but where do I have to write it? Into the navigation options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html) you can make a custom Drawer navigator, so what you need is to create a similar thing to their example:

```
import { DrawerItems, SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (
  <ScrollView>
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  </ScrollView>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

So in your case what you want to do is:

```
    import { DrawerItems, SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';

    const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (
      <ScrollView>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
        <View style={{flex: 1 }}>
              <DrawerItems {...props} />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
              //Your pencil icon here with correct margin to the right
              <Text>Bearbeiten</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </ScrollView>
    );

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
      },
    });
```